# How can I return array from array using map?

Tags: ecmascript-6

Lets say I have an `array`:

```
[['name', 'bulb'],['color', ['red', 'green', 'blue']],[price, ['$52']]]
```

If I use

```
array.map(([key, value]) => `${key}-${value}`)
```

it will return me `array`:

```
['name-bulb', 'color-red,green,blue', 'price-$52']
```

however, I want it to return

```
['name-bulb', 'color-red', 'color-green', 'color-blue', 'price-$52']
```

how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `flatMap` instead with a nested `map`

```js
const data = [['name', 'bulb'],['color', ['red', 'green', 'blue']],['price', ['$52']]]

const result = data.flatMap(([name, value]) => 
  (Array.isArray(value) ? value : [value]).map(value => `${name}-${value}`)
)

console.log(result)
```